# What games come with the Nintendo Switch Online Membership?

Tags: legend-of-zelda-series, mario-series, nintendo-switch-online, metroid-series

I'm considering purchasing a Nintendo Switch Online Membership, and my primary motivation to do this is the classic game collections. Therefore, I would like to know what games in the Mario, Zelda, and Metroid series are available as part of this membership.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the basic subscription you will have access only to [NES](https://www.nintendo.com/store/products/nintendo-entertainment-system-nintendo-switch-online-switch/), [SNES](https://www.nintendo.com/store/products/super-nintendo-entertainment-system-nintendo-switch-online-switch/) and [Gameboy](https://www.nintendo.com/store/products/game-boy-nintendo-switch-online-switch/) titles. With [Nintendo Switch Online - Expansion Pack](https://www.nintendo.com/switch/online/nintendo-switch-online/expansion-pack/) you will get also Nintendo 64, SEGA Mega Drive e Game Boy Advance games.
Here's the basic list:

##### Mario*:

- Mario Bros. (NES)
- Super Mario Bros. (NES)
- Super Mario Bros.: The Lost Levels (NES)
- Super Mario Bros. 2 (NES)
- Super Mario Bros. 3 (NES)
- Dr. Mario (NES)
- Super Mario World (SNES)
- Super Mario World 2: Yoshi's Island (SNES)
- Super Mario Kart (SNES)
- Super Mario All-Stars (SNES)
- Mario's Super Picross (SNES)
- Super Mario Land 2 - 6 Golden Coins (Gameboy)

*(I'm not considering any spin-off like Yoshi or Wario)

##### Zelda:

- The Legend of Zelda (NES)
- Zelda II: The Adventure of Link (NES)
- The Legend of Zelda: A Link to the Past (SNES)
- The Legend of Zelda: Link's Awakening DX (Gameboy)
- The Legend of Zelda: Oracle of Ages (Gameboy)
- The Legend of Zelda: Oracle of Seasons (Gameboy)

##### Metroid:

- Metroid (NES)
- Super Metroid (SNES)
- Metroid II - Return of Samus (Gameboy)

Comment: What about Metroid Fusion?

Comment: @User23415 it is a GBA game.